# How to use UIColliectionView's collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath method asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In UICollectionView when i select a cell, it opens a new UIViewController where some info is displayed.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyClass *myClass = [myClassArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [myClass MyClassInstanceMethod];
}
```

In new `UIViewController` some info about `myClass` instance is printed. However, in `MyClassInstanceMethod` i make some `HTTP` `requests` which get some data and assign to `myClass`'s properties. As you may guess, the problem is `HTTP` `requests` delay and i am not able to get data to be assigned before new view get load.

Then i think that i should **let my `UICollectionView` to open selected cell's page after `MyClassInstanceMethod` finishes it job**. How can i implement that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the web service call? Are you using blocks? Your question is unclear since there is `didSelectZzZ` vs `didDeselectZzZ`.

Comment: what you want exactly ? not getting your question properly

Comment: I do not use blocks. My concern/question is simple, i want `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` to be called new view after some specific method(`MyClassInstanceMethod`) get a response from its HTTP GET method.

Comment: first of all just create an object of class and just call that specific method and then on success you should post a notification and when a notification is recieved on your existing class . here you should change your view controller

Comment: You can pass objectId to next VC and implement loading process there. It's bad UX, when user wait after touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your method encapsulated by the class, you should put a completion handler in your MyClassInstanceMethod. Like

```
- (void)MyClassInstanceMethodWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do your HTTP Requests here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // This will be called just when the http requests finish
            if (completion) { // Here you could check it out if the requests went well
                completion(YES); // If YES return YES
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Inside of the didDeselectItemAtIndexPath: you can call this like:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyClass *myClass = [myClassArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [myClass MyClassInstanceMethodWithCompletion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            // Call the segue
        }
    }];

}
```

I hope this can help.

ps: you have used a method name starting with uppercase MyClass... usually it's better a lowercase myClass... it's a better approach just to differentiate a Class name of a Method name.

Comment: Thanks, for your useful answer and feedback. Thanks to @Vats's answer i see that async may not be necessary(but i've not implemented yet, it may be necessary, too). I'll keep in mind your way. I did not know about async implementation, your answer has sum it up clearly.

Comment: You are welcome. For more information about GCD you can take a look in this link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Answer (score 3):

As my understanding,
you have to make http call in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and in success response you should open your UIViewController with Details you want to show in it.

Comment: You're right, i made direct segue `UICollectionViewCell`  to new `UIViewController`. Now i see that it is better to remove that segue and do my http request stuffs in select method, then make segue job after that.

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak, (just for info.) There is another way to open UIViewController is [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifire:@"viewController"];

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpful. By the way your way works, i did not need to use async.